# How do i fetch data from a customised sanity scheme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am having a hard time understanding the logic of fetching data from sanity,

For example:
I set up a scheme containing an array of images, and each image should have its own string, which i want to use to refer to a class in order to control e.g. the size of the image

So this is what that part of the schema looks like:

```
{
  name: 'images',
  title: 'Images',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    {
      type: 'object',
      name: 'img',
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'size',
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Size',
        },
        {
          name: 'image',
          type: 'image',
          title: 'Image',
          options: {
            hotspot: true,
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Now when i try to fetch the data in order to map over the array i always get errors of "cannot read properties of undefined (reading ..."

This is my useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  sanityClient.fetch(`*[slug.current == "${slug}"]{
    title,
    _id,
    slug,
    style,
    body,
    thumbnail{
        asset->{
            url
        },
    },
    images[]{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url,
        },
      size  

 
    },

    "categories": categories[]->title 
  }`)
    .then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]))
    .catch(console.error);
}, [slug]);
```

and last but not least the map:

```
    {singlePost && singlePost.images && singlePost.images.map((e, index) => ( 
           <Image2 style={e.size} src={e.image.asset.url} key={index} />
    ))}
```

Now i think i messed up the whole useEffect with the "object" thing, but i have no clue on how to maintain it, can somebody help me out with this please?

Comment: Hi James, can you post the actual error ?

Comment: Hi, ive added the error above, am i fetching the data correctly? since it all works just fine when i dont use the scheme with the "size" string...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i was able to finally solve it with the help of sanity vision.

it seems like i made a small mistake when fetching the data,
referring to "object" wasnt needed at all, you can directly fetch the url from the image
this is the corrected code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  sanityClient.fetch(`*[slug.current == "${slug}"]{
    title,
    _id,
    slug,
    style,
    body,
    thumbnail{
        asset->{
            url
        },
    },
    images[]{
      image{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        },
      },
      size
    },
    "categories": categories[]->title 
  }`)
    .then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]))
    .catch(console.error);
}, [slug]);
```

and the map works just simple like this:

```
{singlePost.images.map((e, index) => ( 
       <Image2 style={e.size} src={e.image.asset.url} key={index} />
))}
```